# vpncloud not working on EC2 (Ubuntu) [but works between Azure and GCP]

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, vpn

I'm attempting to set-up VPNcloud (https://github.com/dswd/vpncloud.rs/wiki) as a private VPN for my EC2 instance (running Ubuntu). I'm using this for a private network between this EC2 VM and my GCP and Azure VM's (using the same package on Ubuntu).

All 3 x VMs have static public IP's. The VPN uses private 192.168.1.0/24 addresses defined in the config and in /etc/hosts. The VPN intercepts traffic destined to these private IPs and forwards it through the encrypted tunnels on the public IPs.

The VPN is working between Azure and GCP, but I cannot get the AWS node to play along.

The interface is up (myvpn0).

The port is open.

The process is running.

There is nothing (unusual) in the logs.

I have added an allow Anything from Anywhere f/w rule and that didn't *seem* to help. [I've tested this using netcat and though I suspect this is the issue, netcat is confirming the ports are open].

I have run tshark on the interface and can see outbound traffic (but no inbound responses).

I have run strace on the process and see nothing untoward in the trace. I see the process translate the outbound request onto the destination public IP, but then silence - no response from the destination. On the working Azure/GCP you can see the destinations response.

I can happily ssh between all three servers using their public/static IP numbers.

It *appears* to be something external to the VM, but I can't see what.

Can any spot what I've missed or have any ideas on what to try next?

Thanks,
Pete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED!

AWS enables ufw by default and (sensibly) blocks all ports/traffic.

GCP doesn't enable it.

I've given up on Microsoft due to confusion about their "free" trial tier and no longer have access to the Azure VM.

To fix ...

> ## ufw allow 3310/udp

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your **EC2 Security Group** permits inbound ports for your VPN traffic. Go to EC2 Service -> Instances -> Find your instance -> In the details click on *Security group* and check the rules.

Also if you want to use the VPN instance as a gateway for your other AWS resource you may want to disable the **Source/Destination Check** in the EC2 config as otherwise AWS won't permit routing traffic through this instance.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks MLu, but unfortunately even with all TCP & UDP ports open (and checked remotely using netcat) doesn't seem to help. It's got me completely stumped at the moment!